# How to use adaptive resize on any image in Magento?

Tags: php, image, magento, resize

I found this module, that uses an adaptive resize for product images.     https://github.com/wearefarm/magento-adaptive-resize

Now I'm trying to figure out, how can I use that Adaptive Resize function on any other images in Magento?
I tried calling it like so, but it didn't work:

```
<?php $imager = $this->getSkinUrl('images/thumb_image/something-something.jpg');
$imager = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->AdaptiveResize(100,200);?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a solution. I created a custom module with a helper, that contains a function from the third-party script Zebra Image  http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-image/

Here's the Data.php file in the Helper folder, that I created:

```
class yokubo_customContent_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

    public function resize($img,$target) {
     $ExternalLibPath=Mage::getModuleDir('lib', 'yokubo_customContent'). DS . 'lib' . DS .'Zebra_Image.php';
     require_once ($ExternalLibPath);
     $image = new Zebra_Image();
     $image->source_path = $img;
     $image->target_path = $target; 
     $image->jpeg_quality = 100;
     $image->preserve_aspect_ratio = true;
     $image->enlarge_smaller_images = true;
     $image->preserve_time = true;
     $image->resize(300, 300, ZEBRA_IMAGE_CROP_CENTER);
}
```

And I can now excute it anywhere for any image, by specifing the path and the target directory for the image: `Mage::helper('customContent')->resize($_imageUrl,$imageResized);`